# Recommendation for framework to develop C++ application on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, qt, c++, development

I'm planning to develop an application to serve as a toolkit (for thing I commonly use) for my KUbuntu machine.

I have looked at the QT framework, but can't find any really good guides for development. Alternatively, is there anything else you could suggest for development on Kubuntu?

I have looked at the Quickly framework as well, but is that just for Gnome or Unity on normal Ubuntu?

I have done some C++ before at university, so I should be able to pick it up reasonably quickly. Just not sure where to start with Linux development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the Programming languages are good to use with Kubuntu. But you have to keep in mind that Kubuntu is based in KDE which is based in QT/C++.

So if you want something with a real native look for it, the best practice is to use QT (with the KDE libraries if necessary).

As for tutorials, there are very good tutorials for Qt in the Nokia QT official website here http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/tutorials.html.

But the best place to start if you already know a little bit of C++ is to start with the examples that comes with QtCreator (you can see them on the Start Page when you start QtCreator).

Just see some code, and try some sample stuff like and Hello World, using TextBoxes and change the text on it, and create a sample calculator, so that you can learn the basics of Qt.

If like me you learn better with videos, look a those official qt tutorial videos : http://qt-project.org/videos

Comment: That sounds really good thanks. My only question is how easy is it for QT projects to be used on other platforms aswell?

Comment: It is easy, but it is diferent from Java. The real difference is that you have to compile it for each platform in order to make it work. And to be honest, I don't know any way to compile into a Windows or Mac OsX executable on Linux :S... So I think the best way is to use a real Osx or Windows installation with the right libraries in order to compile. You can see this post for more information if you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963611/creating-executable-for-windows-using-qt-on-linux